# Как получить статус для Issue в GitHub Actions?

Tags: github-actions

Мне нужно при закрытии Issue изменять её статус в проекте ("Done" или "Cancelled") в зависимости от того, как её закрыли: как завершённую или как незапланированную. У меня возникли трудности при получении её статуса.

Мой код:

```
on:
  issues:
    types: closed
  
jobs:
  get_issue_status:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get issue status
        env:
          STATUS: ${{ github.event.issue.status }}
        run: echo $STATUS
```

Результат при закрытии Issue (как завершённая):

[image: Скриншот]

Заранее спасибо за помощь.